# Matplotlib - how to make timer work for live chart

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, charts, plot

The skeleton of the code is pasted below. When I am updating on the timer, the figure is not resizable, and Ctrl+C does not work in the terminal from which I run the python script. I believe the problem is an infinite loop:

```
on_fig_update_event() -> redraw() ->gen_data() ->on_fig_update_event()
```

but I neither know how to break this loop, nor am I sure that this is a problem.
Please take a look at the code below and let me know if you have any ideas:

```
class MyLiveChart(object):

def __init__(self, my_params):
    # Other stuff involving my_params
    plt.connect('button_press_event', self.on_fig_update_event)
    plt.connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_fig_update_event)
    plt.connect('key_press_event', self.on_fig_update_event)

    plt.connect('key_press_event', self.read_input_from_console)
    plt.connect('key_release_event', self.read_input_from_console)
    plt.connect('button_press_event', self.read_input_from_console)
    plt.connect('motion_notify_event', self.read_input_from_console)
    self.run()

def on_fig_update_event(self, _):
    self.redraw()

def redraw(self):
    plt.clf()
    self.gen_data()
    plt.draw()

def run(self):
    self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
    self.gen_data()
# Other stuff
    plt.show()

def gen_data(self):
    # Other stuff
    fig = plt.subplot2grid((num_cols, num_rows), (col, row), rowspan=rowspan,
                               colspan=colspan)
    timer = fig.figure.canvas.new_timer(interval=10000, callbacks=[(self.on_fig_update_event, [None], {})])
    timer.start()
# Other stuff
    plt.grid()
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: try disabling the lines with `plt.connect(..., self.read_input_from_console)` and see if `ctrl-c` works then. You might need to add in handling for `sigint`

Comment: How about the resizing problem?

Comment: It's hard to say, since your code doesn't do anything when run. Could you provide a working example of your code?

Comment: If you want an animated chart, why not just look at the [`matplotlib` example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html), and adjust the `animate` function to do what you want.

Comment: It would also be much safer to use the OO interface here.

Comment: and please fix your indentation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the OO interface?